# $f$ is irreducible iff $V(f)$ is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I would like to know if the following statement is true:

> $f$ is irreducible iff $V(f)$ is irreducible.

My tools I'm trying to use to prove this are Study's Lemma and basic algebra.

If $f$ is reducible, we have $f=f_1\cdot f_2$ which implies $V(f)=V(f_1)\cup V(f_2)$ where $f_i$ are non units, but that doesn't guarantee that $V(f_1)\neq V(f_2)$. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Conversely, suppose $V(f)$ irreducible, if $f=f_1\cdot f_2$, we have $V(f)=V(f_1)\cup V(f_2)$, since $V(f)$ is irreducible, $V(f_1)=V(f_2)$ and by study's lemma $f_1$ and $f_2$ are associates, but this not necessarily implies that $f_1$ or $f_2$ is an unit.

I think this statement is not true, can anyone help me which side is true and why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, it's not true. If $f$ is irreducible, $V(f)$ is irreducible, but $V(f)=V(f^2)$.

Comment: That's already quite explicit. Take _any_ irreducible $f$.

Comment: And for the other direction, which is true, don't conclude that $V(f_1) = V(f_2)$. Instead, assume w.l.o.g. that $V(f_1)$ is non-empty and conclude that $V(f) = V(f_1)$. This implies that $f$ and $f_1$ are associates, making $f_2$ a unit.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629389/vf-is-irreducible-iff-f-gk-g-irreducible

Comment: An example of f is irreducible but V(f) is reducible https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472502/