# Show that the polynomial $Y^2+X^2(X-1)^2 \in \Bbb R[X,Y]$ is irreducible.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I'm studying basic algebraic geometry (from Fulton's *Algebraic Curves*). I'm required to show that the polynomial $$Y^2+X^2(X-1)^2 \in \Bbb R[X,Y]$$ is irreducible. I'm not that familiar with multivariable polynomials. How does one in general tackle such problems?

Comment: It is easy to factorize this in irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$. Hope the rest is clear.

Comment: Hello John:  in general, a title of the form "question from subject area" is a terrible title. This time I've changed it to something more useful. Please be mindful of this for future titles... thanks!

Comment: Related but clearly not duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1472502/29335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are many ways. In this particular case the degree in $Y$ is low, so it is not hard to try to factor the polynomial 'by brute force'. If the polynomial factors, then it factors into two factors that are linear in $Y$, meaning that there exist $a(X),b(X),c(X),d(X)\in\Bbb{R}[X]$ such that
$$Y^2+X^2(X-1)^2=(a(X)Y+b(X))(c(X)Y+d(X)),$$
which quickly leads to a contradiction.